# Syntax error near unexpected token '('

Tags: c, linux

As a beginner, I am trying to write a simple c program to learn and execute the "write" function.

I am trying to execute a simple c program simple_write.c

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    if ((write(1, “Here is some data\n”, 18)) != 18)
         write(2, “A write error has occurred on file descriptor 1\n”,46);
    exit(0);
}
```

I also execute chmod +x simple_write.c

But when i execute ./simple_write.c, it gives me **syntax error near unexpected token '('**

Couldn't figure out why this happens ??

P.S: The expected output is:-

```
$ ./simple_write
Here is some data
$
```

Comment: Why are you using `“` and `”` rather than `"` as it should be?

Comment: Are you asking about the line if ((write(1, “Here is some data\n”, 18)) != 18) ??

Comment: Well i am using " itself...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok,

I got what i was doing wrong.

These are the steps that I took to get my problem corrected:-

1. `$ gedit simple_write.c`
2. Write the code into this file and save it (with .c extension).
3. `$ make simple_write`
4. `$ ./simple_write`

And I got the desired output.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

You did

```
$ chmod +x simple_write.c
$ ./simple_write.c
```

when you should have done

```
$ cc simple_write.c -o simple_write
$ chmod +x simple_write                 # On second thought, you probably don’t need this.
$ ./simple_write
```

In words: ***compile*** the program to create an executable `simple_write`
(*without* **`.c`**) file, and then run that. 
What you did was attempt to execute your C source code file
as a shell script.

Notes:

- The `simple_write` file will be a binary file. 
  Do not look at it with tools meant for text files
  (e.g., `cat`, `less`, or text editors such as `gedit`).
- `cc` is the historical name for the C compiler. 
  If you get `cc: not found` (or something equivalent),
  try the command again with `gcc` (GNU C compiler). 
  If that doesn’t work,

  - If you’re on a shared system (e.g., school or library),
    ask a system administrator how to compile a C program.
  - If you’re on your personal computer (i.e., you’re the administrator),
    you will need to install the compiler yourself (or get a friend to do it). 
    There’s lots of guidance written about this; just search for it.
- When you get to writing more complicated programs,
  you are going to want to use

  ```
  make simple_write
  ```

  which has the advantages of

  - being able to orchestrate a multi-step build,
    which is typical for complex programs, and
  - it knows the standard ways of compiling programs on that system
    (for example, it will probably “know” whether to use `cc` or `gcc`).

  And, in fact, you should be able to use the above command now. 
  This may (or may not) simplify your life.

---

P.S. Now that this question is on Stack Overflow,
I’m allowed to talk about the programming aspect of it. 
It looks to me like it should compile, but

- The first `write` line has more parentheses than it needs.

  ```
  if (write(1, "Here is some data\n", 18) != 18)
  ```

  should work.
- In the second `write` line,
  I count the string as being 48 characters long, not 46.
- By the way, do you know how to make the first `write` fail,
  so the second one will execute?  Try

  > `./simple_write >&-`

Answer (score 5):

You cannot execute C source code in Linux (or other systems) directly.

C is a language that requires compilation to binary format.

You need to install C [compiler](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) (the actual procedure differs depending on your system), compile your program and only then you can execute it.

Currently it was interpreted by shell. The first two lines starting with `#` were ignored as comments. The third line caused a syntax error.